# Python scraping: Is there a way to use multiple attributes with find_all after pulling in the data with bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am pulling data from a table of numbers using this code. I only need a few of the data elements so I pop off the unneeded data after placing it in a list.
[Example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fytP4.png)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
vals = soup.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "W(39%) Fl(start)"})
for val in vals:
    PullList.append(val.text)
seq = [20, 19, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 1]
for t in seq:
    PullList.pop(t)
print(PullList)
```

"span", attrs={"class": "W(39%) Fl(start) only refers to the data in columns 1,3 & 5 of the example table above.

The problem I have is that sometimes the data table includes a negative number and the html code turns the number red in the table.  The attribute in the span definition now changes to "W(39%) Fl(start) C($c-fuji-red-2-b)" from "W(39%) Fl(start)".  Because I am using a specific attrs value the red (negative) numbers are not meeting the the find_all statement requirements and thus not pulled into the list.

Is there a way to use multiple values in the attrs definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can currently use css selector to target that column and slice off header

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

tickers = ['PSHAX','FKAIX']

def get_list(s, ticker):
    r = s.get(f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{ticker}/risk?p={ticker}')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    three_year = [i.text for i in soup.select('div:nth-child(2) > span.W\(39\%\).Fl\(start\)')]
    if len(three_year) > 0:
        return three_year[1:]
    return 

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in tickers:
        print(get_list(s, ticker))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Being new to python, I had problems with the syntax.  I will have to go do my homework on syntax.  I did use the select function instead of find_all function in my soup call.  It pulled back a list where I was able to find the index number of the title for each data element.  I then increment the index by one and pulled in the data element.  Once again, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Here is my code that ultimately worked. 
    for tick in TickList:
        TickPath1 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/XXXXX/risk?p=XXXXX"
        TickPath = TickPath1.replace("XXXXX", tick)
        response = requests.get(TickPath)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        vals = soup.select("span", attrs={"class": "W(39%) Fl(start)"})
        for val in vals:
            PullList.append(val.text)
        # look for specific element labels
        a = (PullList.index("Alpha"))
        d = PullList[(a + 1)]
        DataList.append(d)

Comment: so what would be an example url in full?

Comment: The first URL is all positive values.  The second has some negative values.  The table on these pages is called "Risk Statistics".  thank you for your help

Comment: Do you want the entire table as a table? If not, looking at https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FKAIX/risk?p=FKAIX, which columns do you want? And do you want them as a single list?

Comment: finance.yahoo.com/quote/PSHAX/risk?p=PSHAX is a better example because it contains negative numbers.  I am only looking at capturing the first data column of the table in a list.  Thanks

Comment: Not sure if updated code will work for a long time but give it a go.